# RegEx to pull objects containing key-value pairs from "array like" string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this below:

```
"[name:pizza,quantity:12,unit_price:3.43],[name:burger,unit_price:40.47,quantity:24],[quantity:4,unit_price:14.47,name:hotdog]";
```

Here name, quantity and unit_price not in a sequence for every group.
I want to apply regex on this string and extract data like below:

1. Group one:
   name- **pizza**,
   quantity- **12**,
   unit_price- **3.43**
2. Group two:
   name- **burger**,
   quantity- **24**,
   unit_price- **40.47**
3. ...
   I have tried this pattern so far:

   ```
   (\{(?:name:(?<name>[a-zA-Z\s]+))|(?:amount:(?<amount>[0-9]+))|(?:unit_price:(?<unitPrice>[0-9]+.?[0-9]*))\})
   ```

But I don't know how to extract every nested group. And I also think this pattern is not right for this following string.

Now how do I do this in java in pure regex without splitting and iterating?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and also read [ask]

Comment: please explain for negative vote.

Comment: Did you read the contents of the [help] and [ask]?  You are expected to attempt a solution on your own and then show what you have done so far.  StackOverflow is not a tutorial site of a place where other people do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes:

- there are no additional characters before the initial `[` or after the last `]`.
- The value of `name`, `quantity` etc contain neither `,` or `]`.

### Regular Expression

```
\G\[(?:(?:name:(?<name>[^,\]]+)|quantity:(?<quantity>[^,\]]+)|unit_price:(?<unit_price>[^,\]]+)),?)*\](?:,|\z)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gW2cL1/1

### Visualisation

[image: RegEx Visualisation]

### Code

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\G\\[(?:(?:name:(?<name>[^,\\]]+)|quantity:(?<quantity>[^,\\]]+)|unit_price:(?<unit_price>[^,\\]]+)),?)*\\](?:,|\\z)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text for "name": regexMatcher.group("name")
        // matched text for "quantity": regexMatcher.group("quantity")
        // matched text for "unit_price": regexMatcher.group("unit_price")
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

### Human Readable

```
// \G\[(?:(?:name:(?<name>[^,\]]+)|quantity:(?<quantity>[^,\]]+)|unit_price:(?<unit_price>[^,\]]+)),?)*\](?:,|\z)
// 
// Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Default line breaks
// 
// Assert position at the end of the previous match (the start of the string for the first attempt) «\G»
// Match the character “[” literally «\[»
// Match the regular expression below «(?:(?:name:(?<name>[^,\]]+)|quantity:(?<quantity>[^,\]]+)|unit_price:(?<unit_price>[^,\]]+)),?)*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//    Match the regular expression below «(?:name:(?<name>[^,\]]+)|quantity:(?<quantity>[^,\]]+)|unit_price:(?<unit_price>[^,\]]+))»
//       Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «name:(?<name>[^,\]]+)»
//          Match the character string “name:” literally (case insensitive) «name:»
//          Match the regex below and capture its match into a backreference named “name” (also backreference number 1) «(?<name>[^,\]]+)»
//             Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^,\]]+»
//                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//                The literal character “,” «,»
//                The literal character “]” «\]»
//       Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «quantity:(?<quantity>[^,\]]+)»
//          Match the character string “quantity:” literally (case insensitive) «quantity:»
//          Match the regex below and capture its match into a backreference named “quantity” (also backreference number 2) «(?<quantity>[^,\]]+)»
//             Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^,\]]+»
//                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//                The literal character “,” «,»
//                The literal character “]” «\]»
//       Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «unit_price:(?<unit_price>[^,\]]+)»
//          Match the character string “unit_price:” literally (case insensitive) «unit_price:»
//          Match the regex below and capture its match into a backreference named “unit_price” (also backreference number 3) «(?<unit_price>[^,\]]+)»
//             Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^,\]]+»
//                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//                The literal character “,” «,»
//                The literal character “]” «\]»
//    Match the character “,” literally «,?»
//       Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
// Match the character “]” literally «\]»
// Match the regular expression below «(?:,|\z)»
//    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «,»
//       Match the character “,” literally «,»
//    Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\z»
//       Assert position at the very end of the string «\z»
```

### Additional Notes

You didn't specify any specific rules for the type of data `name` or any of the other values could be.

So "one or more characters that is not `,` and not `]`" was the obvious choice.

To be more specific adjust the regular expression to capture only the data you want in place of the `[^,\]]+` elements.

So for `name` you might use `[a-z]{3,10}` to match `a` through `z` without any spaces between 3 and 10 times. The `name` value won't be captured if it doesn't match.

As already mentioned in comments changing `,?` for `(?:,|(?=\])` will ensure you match a `,` or `]` at the end of each item.

Comment: The optional `,` would allow garbage input such as `[name:pizzaquantity:12,unit_price:3.43]`. The standard solution is `token (separator token)*` If you don't like repeating the portion of the regex, just build the regex with string concat. By the way, a syntax explanation of a regex is almost always useless, unless the pattern is extremely simple.

Comment: Because of the `\G` anchor point the it simply captures `pizzaquantity:12` as the `name` value - which it could very well be - a non-issue. Garbage in garbage out. If it was a worry I would switch it for a simple lookahead changing `,?` for `(?:,|(?=\])`.  Personally I always find syntax outline useful - to each their own.

Comment: nice graph (and nice site): how do you get it ?

Comment: @DeanTaylor: My aim is to make the regex do garbage in, nothing out instead. If it's possible to exclude the error, then it's better to do it here instead of post-process the result or use garbage data.

Comment: Added some additional notes.